# How can I find out when a morphing triangle will hit a point?

Tags: math, geometry, collision, intersection

I have a deforming triangle 3d, whose vertices all move between t0 and t1.

Halfway there is a point that will collide with the triangle.

Having only the coordinates of the triangles and the point, how do I calculate the exact time (between t0 and t1) that the triangle hits the point?

Note: the triangles do not have the same normal and the vertices move with uniform velocity.

Here's an image that hopefully helps illustrate the question better:
[image]

Comment: Are triangles parallel? Is moving law the same for all three vertices? You omit important details again.

Comment: @MBo, updated description, thanks

Comment: "the triangles do not have the same normal" - so these are 3d triangles, and the picture is a projection of the reality ?

Comment: Feels like this question should be on [math.se], but anyway. Make equations of the plane of the triangle at `t0` and the plane of the triangle at `t1`. Use those to make a parameterised equation of the plane at time `t` (between `t0` and `t1`). Plug in the coordinates of the point of interest, and solve for `t`.